# Multiple cascade paths error entity framework Code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am aware that this has been raised on numerous occasions but
none of the provided answers seem to help.I am aware of
the basic problem and have used fluent api to try to modify it's
behaviour but it appears this is being ignored(or i'm doing it wrong'.
Here's a example of the
code in question

```
public class Request
{
    [Key]
    public int RequestID { get; set; }
    public string RequestDescription { get; set; }
    public int RequestPriority { get; set; }
    public string RequestStub { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Requester")]
    public int RequesterID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Admin")]
    public int AdminID { get; set; }
    public bool RequestAnsweredFlag { get; set; }
    public bool RequestSeenFlag { get; set; }


    public virtual User Requester {get;set;}
    public virtual User Admin { get; set; }
```

}

context class

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {


        modelBuilder.Entity<Request>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.Requester)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(u => u.RequesterID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Request>().HasRequired(a => a.Admin)
                       .WithMany()
                       .HasForeignKey(u => u.AdminID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    }
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand all correct you need to delete attributes  [ForeignKey("Requester")],  [ForeignKey("Admin")] and delete fluent api rules. And modify your code as follow

```
public class Request
{
    [Key]
    public int RequestID { get; set; }
    public string RequestDescription { get; set; }
    public int RequestPriority { get; set; }
    public string RequestStub { get; set; }
    public int RequesterID { get {return Requester.Id} }
    public int AdminID { get {return Admin.Id} }
    public bool RequestAnsweredFlag { get; set; }
    public bool RequestSeenFlag { get; set; }

    public virtual User Requester {get;set;}
    public virtual User Admin { get; set; }

}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
}
```

it should map all correctly by default

Comment: He should have marked this as answer, it works for me perfectly :)